# Cannot set overriddencreatedon when creating entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 On premise.

According to http://mostlymscrm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/understanding-createdon-and.html overriddencreatedon can be set when creating a new record to override the default value for createdon.

I am using Simego Data Synchronisation Studio to create some records in CRM and when I set the value of overriddencreatedon to one date time value, the UTC date time when the record was created is used instead.

Comment: maybe you are setting createdon field too?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I'm not

Comment: @GuidoPreite I was thinking that setting the created on field was completely ignored.  Am I wrong in that?

Comment: Any chance that Simego is doing a create and then an update?  I'd turn on Tracing using the CRM Diagnostics tool and see what sort of create / updates the Simego tool is doing.

Comment: @Daryl because it's done by an external app I don't know the behavior, when I need to use the overriddencreatedon I never set the createdon too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Simego support:

"When you set a value in overriddencreatedon the createdon field will receive this new value but overriddencreatedon will receive the datetime the record was actually created."

Answer (score 1):

The overridecreatedon field is used in all of the display fields/forms in the user interface so the user can understand the original created date. This is useful when the data comes from another systems or processes and you want the users to see the original date.

In the underlying createdon field will always be the date time that the entity was created.

Manually changing the createdon field in the SQL CRM is not advised as it can interfere with auditing, workflows and other internal processes.